# __init__() takes 6 positional arguments but 7 were given

Tags: python, oop

I've only been learning python for a week, before that I didn't really understand the concept of inheritance, I want to ask, how should I use child_class(parent1, parent2)?

thank you,

here's my code I attached

```
class Mobil:
    def __init__(self, warna, plat, nomor_rangka, nomor_mesin):
        self.warna = warna
        self.plat = plat
        self.nomor_rangka = nomor_rangka
        self.nomor_mesin = nomor_mesin

class MobilBBM(Mobil):
    def __init__(self, warna, plat, nomor_rangka, nomor_mesin, bbm):
      super().__init__(warna, plat, nomor_rangka, nomor_mesin)
      self.bbm = bbm

class MobilListrik(Mobil):
    def __init__(self, warna, plat, nomor_rangka, nomor_mesin, baterai):
        super().__init__(warna, plat, nomor_rangka, nomor_mesin)
        self.baterai = baterai

class MobilHybrida(MobilListrik, MobilBBM):
    def __init__(self, warna, plat, nomor_rangka, nomor_mesin, baterai, bbm):
      super().__init__(warna, plat, nomor_rangka, nomor_mesin, baterai, bbm)

mobil = MobilHybrida('Hitam','B','12','13','Pertalite','Water')
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Neither parent of `MobilHybrida` expects all of those arguments. See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for advice on how to use `super` with multiple inheritance. (Short version: use `**kwargs` in the definition and call `MobilHybrida` with keyword arguments.)

Answer (score 1):

`MobilListrik` and `MobilBBM` share 4 arguments, but each expects a different 5th argument. You can't simply pass *all* 6 arguments to `super().__init__` as positional arguments and expect the correct ones to go to the correct parent.

The standard advice is to use keyword arguments with `__init__` in a multiple inheritance situation. Each `__init__` will grab the arguments they expect and pass the rest on up the tree.

```
class Mobil:
    def __init__(self, *, warna, plat, nomor_rangka, nomor_mesin, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.warna = warna
        self.plat = plat
        self.nomor_rangka = nomor_rangka
        self.nomor_mesin = nomor_mesin


class MobilBBM(Mobil):
    def __init__(self, *, bbm, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.bbm = bbm


class MobilListrik(Mobil):
    def __init__(self, *, baterai, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.baterai = baterai


# Note that MobilHybrida.__init__ doesn't even need to be defined.
class MobilHybrida(MobilListrik, MobilBBM):
    pass


# I'm guessing at which values go with which parameters.
mobil = MobilHybrida(warna='Hitam', plat='B', nomor_rangka='12', nomor_mesin='13', bbm='Pertalite', baterai='Water')
```